# Simplify $2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + .... + 2 + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + .... + 2 + 1$
I know the answer is $2^n - 1$, but how to simplify it?

Comment: What happens if you add $1$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First way:

$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+...+a^2b^{n-3}+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$

set a=2, b=1

Edit: Second way.

Set $X=2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + … + 2 + 1$

$2X=2^n+2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + … + 2$

$2X=2^n+2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + … + 2 +1 -1$

$2X=2^n+X-1$

$X=2^n-1$

Answer (score 5):

Observe that it is a [Geometric Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation) with the first term $=2^{n-1}$ and common ratio $=\frac12$

Comment: to the Downvoter, please  pinpoint the mistake

Comment: Someone seems to have downvoted all the answers, and is possibly out on a downvoting spree also on other questions. I've flagged this for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

let $S= 1+x+x^2+.......+x^{n-1}$ where $x\ne1$

Multiply this equation by $x$ on both sides and get:

$xS= x+x^2+...........+x^{n}$

now subtract the second equality from the first one and you will end up with:

$(1-x)S= 1+x+x^2+.....+x^{n-1}-x-x^2-.......-x^n$

simplify:

$(1-x)S=1-x^n$ which implies that $S=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} $

when $x=2$;  $S=\frac{1-2^n}{1-2}=2^n-1$

Comment: This is possible only when $x\ne1$, just to be clear.

Comment: thanks for reminding me i forgot to mention that. when x =1the sum is trivial.

Comment: now it is mentioned in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\\ \text{Let } 2^{(n-1)} + 2^{(n-2)} + \cdots + 2 + 1 &=& S 
\\  2^{n} + 2^{(n-1)} + .... + 2^2 + 2 &=& 2S \tag {multiply both sides by 2}
\\  2^{n} + 2^{(n-1)} + .... + 2^2 + 2 +1 &=& 2S +1\tag {add 1 to both sides }
\\  2^{n} + S &=& 2S +1\tag {replace the term on LHS by S }
\\  2^{n}  &=& S +1\tag {subtract S from both sides }
\\  2^{n} -1  &=& S
\\  S &=& 2^{n} -1 \quad \square  
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

$2^{n-1}+\cdots+2^{0}=\left(2-1\right)\left(2^{n-1}+\cdots+2^{0}\right)=\left(2^{n}+\cdots+2^{1}\right)-\left(2^{n-1}+\cdots+2^{0}\right)=2^{n}-1$

Answer (score 1):

Forget about all the smart generic formulas. Just rewrite the last summand $1$ as $2-1$. You get
$$
2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2 + 2 - 1.
$$
Now group the $2$'s together. $2 + 2 = 2^2$, so you get
$$
2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^2 - 1
$$
Now group $2^2$ and $2^2$ together to get $2^2 + 2^2 = 2^3$:
$$
2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^3 + 2^3 - 1
$$
If you go on in this fashion, you will eventually come to $2^n - 1$. The actual number of steps in this process depends on $n$, so technically this should be framed as a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Another "proof" (this was actually the way I had "proved" it myself until I saw the GP proof):

The first summand is 1 followed by a $n-1$ in base 2. The later ones are with one less zero every time. Adding them up results in a number composed of 1 followed by n-1 zeros, which is $2^n-1$ (1 followed by n zeros minus one).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by induction. The goal is to show that for all $n \ge 0$, $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1}$

First consider the base case $n=0$. This checks out because $2^0 = 1 = 2^1 -1$

Now $\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i = 2^n +2^n -1 = 2*2^n -1 =2^{n+1} -1$.