# Prove $Z(f)$ is a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: \Bbb R$ → $\Bbb R$ is continuous and define the zero set of $f$ by

$Z(f) =$ { $x : f(x) = 0$}

How would I prove that $Z(f)$ is a closed set?

Comment: what did you try? which definition of closed set are you using?

Comment: Also, what definition of continuity do you know? As it stands, this set is just $f^{-1}(\{0\})$, which is closed because $\{0\}$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Notice that $Z\left(f\right)$ is exactly the preimage of set
$\left\{ 0\right\} $. This set $\left\{ 0\right\} $ is closed in
space $\mathbb{R}$ if it is equipped with its usual topology.

Comment: Downvotes should be explained.

Comment: I'm ashamed that somebody downvoted this answer.

Comment: @egreg. No shame on you. Someone is doing some strange things at the moment. For instance at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/590733/75923 all answers are downvoted too.

Comment: @drhab , it is an old "tradition" in this site: from time to time, somebody (most probably one, perhaps several) gets into downvoting rage without any consideration for the answer's quality. A pity, but apparently unavoidable. Don't take it hard, it really doesn't matter, and in the meantime I shall upvote here to compensate. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio. Thank you for this explanation (and your upvote). A thought: why not making it impossible to downvote if a comment has not been given yet. This will make it more easy to find out who is trying to be 'funny' and can withhold people. By the way, off course I dislike this phenomenon, but I am not really bothered by it. Secondly $18>10$.

Comment: Hehe...I agree with you, @drhab...and not only that but many things, me believes, could be seriously enhanced in this site, but in the meanwhile....

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Under continuous functions, inverse images of open sets are open. What does this mean about inverse images of closed sets? Is $\{0\}$ a closed set?

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this please explain their reasons?

Comment: read my comment in the other answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it. Take open sets $(0, \infty)$ and $(- \infty, 0 ) $. In fact, their union $(- \infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty) $ is an open set since unions of open sets are open by definitions. Now, we use the hypothesis that we are given: the continuity of $f$. By definition, we that then that
 $$f^{-1}[ (- \infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty) ) ] = f^{-1}(-\infty,0) \cup f^{-1}(0,\infty)$$

must be open set. Put $U = f^{-1}(-\infty,0) \cup f^{-1}(0,\infty)$. But, by definition, the complement of $U$ must be closed. And hence $U^c = Z(f) $(proof?) must be closed. The problem is now solved.