# How to derive $2^k-1$ from $2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+...+2^{k-k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k\in N$, I have series of additions $2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+...+2^{k-k}$. From trial and error I got it equal to $2^k-1$ but I am failing to understand how to derive it. For example $2^{k-1}$ will make $2^1$ difference and so on. I will end up with $2^1+2^2+...+2^k$ differences per say which is clearly not equal $2^k-1$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590733/simplify-2n-1-2n-2-2-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let s = $2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}+...+2^{k-k}$

s = $2^{k-k}+2^{k-k+1}+...+2^{k-1}$
            =>s=$1+2^1+...+2^{k-1}$ ---(1)

now consider 2*s = $2^1+2^2+...+2^k$ ----(2)

subtract (2) & (1) you will get s = $2^k-1$

Answer (score 1):

If we write your sum as $S:=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k$, then $$ S=(2-1)S=2S-S=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}2^k-\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k=2^{n+1}-1 $$